# how to make an IP address link

Tags: links, hyperlink

So I have made a website. I have not, however, registered any domain name linked to the IP address.  I would like to make it so that people can open it directly from pdf generated by Latex, without needing to paste and type it in their browser. \href seems to only support url, not IP address?Is it doable?

Comment: I would have expected that `\url{https://ip-address}` or whatever you would type in a browser bar works. Did you try?

Comment: OK，so I have to type https// before hand.sorry dumb mistake